# Use Apportable to port ios app to android app: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, apportable

I stuck in this error
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'`

when try "apportable load"
Who can help me?
Here is detail log in terminal:

raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ducnm/.apportable/SDK/bin/apportable", line 845, in <module>
    run(env)
  File "/Users/ducnm/.apportable/SDK/bin/apportable", line 781, in run
    results = actions[args.action](env)
  File "/Users/ducnm/.apportable/SDK/bin/apportable", line 86, in LoadAction
    return env.LoadApp(site_init.BuildApplication(env, env['BUILD_TARGET']))
  File "/Users/ducnm/.apportable/SDK/site_scons/site_init.py", line 390, in BuildApplication
    return build.App(env, app_sconscript)
  File "/Users/ducnm/.apportable/SDK/site_scons/build/__init__.py", line 556, in App
    results = env.BuildApp(sources=sources, header_paths=headers, defines=defines, flags=flags, config=configs, deps=deps, libs=libs, java_libs=java_libs, assets=assets, pch=pchs, modules=modules, java_sources=java_sources, java_sourcepaths=java_sourcepaths, java_res_dirs=java_res_dirs)
  File "/Users/ducnm/.apportable/SDK/lib/scons/engine/SCons/Environment.py", line 223, in __call__
    return self.method(*nargs, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ducnm/.apportable/SDK/site_scons/site_init.py", line 1204, in BuildApp
    build.Module(env, module["build_cwd"], module)
  File "/Users/ducnm/.apportable/SDK/site_scons/build/__init__.py", line 577, in Module
    target_file_name_base = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(target["project"] + ".approj", "targets", target["target"], target["project_config"]))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 66, in join
    if b.startswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object` usually indicates a missing symbol to the linker. Look higher up in the log for missing symbols.

Background: `apportable load` does a parallel build which leads to more logging after the fatal error. The parallel build can be disabled with the option -j1.

Comment: Ah, it is another build system error. This thread might be helpful https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/apportable-discuss/Zxan_7UFrnE. Other than that, if it's possible to simplify/minimize your Xcode subproject structure. Otherwise the next SDK release 1.1.05 has multiple build system fixes that might help you.

Comment: Thank u. I pass through "AttributeError". But now, I get a new problem with AFNetwork library.
/Classes/AFURLConnectionOperation.h:186:1: error: 
      property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t completionQueue;

Comment: AFNetworking 2.0 is not yet supported. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/apportable-discuss/iZC1H47hdNY/9Aj72UWRf3kJ